# Does ObservableCollection maintain insertion order?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if an ObservableCollection is guaranteed to maintain the order of elements inserted into it in C#. I looked at the MSDN site but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is derived from `Collection<T>`, which uses `IList<T> items` to store data. When adding and removing items `ObservableCollection` just delegates call to base class, for example.

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
{
  this.CheckReentrancy();
  base.InsertItem(index, item);
  this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
  this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
  this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, (object) item, index);
}
```

`Collection` in C# in an ordered data structure, so the relative order of items after inserting and deleting shouldn't change.

Answer (score 11):

### Yes.

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, which means that items are stored in the order you specify.

---

As a general rule, this is how the basic collection types in .NET work.

`IEnumerable<T>` allows you to access the items one at a time, in an unspecified order.

`ICollection<T>` allows you to add and remove items, and access the total size of the collection, in addition to `IEnumerable<T>` capabilities.

`IList<T>` allows you to access items by index and insert and remove items at arbitrary indices, in addition to `ICollection<T>` capabilities.

Comment: Take careful note of his wording: "in the order *you specify*", which means that if you use any of the insert methods (instead of the `Add` method), the last item added may not necessarily be at the last index, though is still in *your specified* order.

Answer (score 6):

Please see the excerpts below from [ObservableCollection Class MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) documentation:

**Methods:**

```
Add         Adds an object to the *end* of the Collection<T>. (Inherited from Collection<T>.)

Insert      Inserts an element into the Collection<T> at the *specified index*. (Inherited from Collection<T>.)

InsertItem  Inserts an item into the collection at the *specified index*. (Overrides Collection<T>.InsertItem(Int32, T).)
```

**Explicit Interface Implementation:**

```
IList.Add      Adds an item to the IList. (Inherited from Collection<T>.)

IList.Insert   Inserts an item into the IList at the specified index. (Inherited from Collection<T>.)
```